# Bat file Disconnecting a network drive if it exists

Tags: batch-file, dos

I need your help.

How can a batch file be written to check to see if a network drive is connected and if it is ask the user to Y/N to delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something along these lines...

```
if exist n:\. goto network
goto :eof

:network
SET /P remove=Remove network (Y/N)
if !%remove%!==!Y! net use n: /delete
```